# Can't fetch an entity from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I use following lines of code to fetch an object of type of Products with specified ID (theID) from core data, although every thing seems ok and I am sure theID exists in core data but the result is always empty.

```
-(Products *) currentTargetInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context withMyId:(NSString *)theID
{
    Products * match;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Products" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [request setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myid == %@", theID];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    match = nil;
    if (objects == nil)
    {
        // handle the error
    }
    else
    {
        if ([objects count] > 0)
        {
            match = (Products *)[objects firstObject];
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

What could be wrong in the code?

Comment: Enable SQL debugging to see what query is being performed.
To enable it  Edit Scheme of the target, there you can add an Argument Passed On Launch.
Add -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1

Comment: Is ID also stored as String in the Database? Is the spelling of "myid" correct? Set a breakpoint after the predicate and print the request (as SQL-String). Try to request all Products (so without predicate). Comment the `setReturn...`and `setResultType`.

Comment: `setReturnsDistinctResults` only works with the NSDictionaryResultType

Answer (score 1):

try changing NSPredicate Code, use just single ' = ' sign.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myid = %@", theID];
```

Comment: "=" and "==" in a predicate are completely equivalent, the is no difference at all.

Comment: check the theID value, is the value not nil or some value which may not be in the DB, you can check your core data db also using FireFox SQLite Manager extension

Answer (score 0):

Use the following statement:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myid LIKE[c] %@", theID];
```

Hope this one solves you problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myid == \"%@\"", theID];
```

instead of

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myid == %@", theID];
```

Answer (score -1):

What i think is there can be a 2-3 problem here , which can lead these errors you are getting .

First i advise you make sure check that there is a item in your product entity with id you are searching , means first print all product entity rows so that we can sure we are searching right thing .

Then second have you set the `managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext`
here appDelegate is object of AppDelegate class,import AppDelegate in which file you are calling this method

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

1. Check the type of **theID** you set , if it is string then its good , but generally people and i also used to take ids like this in  NSNumber , if it is NSNumber convert your string in NSNumber

4.After checking all these above points ,run code by commenting these lines in your code

```
request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];
```

if all these points does not help you can you show us ur productEntity NSManagedObjectClass .h and .m

Comment: Y -1 ,did u checked these all ?